# Classifying array of strings into the closes regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following array:

```
 a
=> ["http://dominio-1-736865.com/path1",
 "http://dominio-2-570941.com/path2",
 "http://102.160.194.146/path4",
 "http://142.231.2.110",
 "http://142.231.2.110/path/inventado",
 "http://dominio-3-468658.com/path2",
 "http://dominio-3-468658.com/path2/path1",
 "http://dominio-3-468658.com/path2/path2",
 "http://subdominio.dominio-3-468658.com/path2",
 "http://www.dominio-3-468658.com/path2",
 "http://este-se-repite.re/AP-448055"]
```

Then I need to group like this:

```
fqdns
=> ["dominio-1-736865.com", "dominio-2-570941.com", "102.160.194.146", "142.231.2.110", "dominio-3-468658.com", "subdominio.dominio-3-468658.com", "este-se-repite.re"]
```

getting this =

```
["http://dominio-1-736865.com/path1"]
["http://dominio-2-570941.com/path2"]
["http://102.160.194.146/path4"]
["http://142.231.2.110", "http://142.231.2.110/path/inventado"]
["http://dominio-3-468658.com/path2", "http://dominio-3-468658.com/path2/path1", "http://dominio-3-468658.com/path2/path2", "http://www.dominio-3-468658.com/path2"]
["http://subdominio.dominio-3-468658.com/path2"]
["http://este-se-repite.re/AP-448055"]
```

The problem is with subdominio.dominio-3-468658.com, and dominio3-468658.com, that can be in two but I need to meet only in the one that has the subdomain. how can achieve this in ruby

```
[25] pry(#<Notifications::Notification>)> a.map{|d| d.match(fqdns[1])}
=> [nil, #<MatchData "dominio-2-570941.com">, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
[26] pry(#<Notifications::Notification>)> a.map{|d| d.match(fqdns[0])}
=> [#<MatchData "dominio-1-736865.com">, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
[27] pry(#<Notifications::Notification>)> a.map{|d| d.match(fqdns[2])}
=> [nil, nil, #<MatchData "102.160.194.146">, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
[28] pry(#<Notifications::Notification>)> a.map{|d| d.match(fqdns[3])}
=> [nil, nil, nil, #<MatchData "142.231.2.110">, #<MatchData "142.231.2.110">, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
[29] pry(#<Notifications::Notification>)> a.map{|d| d.match(fqdns[4])}
=> [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, #<MatchData "dominio-3-468658.com">, #<MatchData "dominio-3-468658.com">, #<MatchData "dominio-3-468658.com">, #<MatchData "dominio-3-468658.com">, #<MatchData "dominio-3-468658.com">, nil]
[30] pry(#<Notifications::Notification>)> a.map{|d| d.match(fqdns[5])}
=> [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, #<MatchData "subdominio.dominio-3-468658.com">, nil, nil]
[31] pry(#<Notifications::Notification>)> a.map{|d| d.match(fqdns[6])}
=> [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, #<MatchData "este-se-repite.re">]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to add regexes here (and create another problem). Use the right tool for the job: URI parsers.

```
uris = ["http://dominio-1-736865.com/path1",
 "http://dominio-2-570941.com/path2",
 "http://102.160.194.146/path4",
 "http://142.231.2.110",
 "http://142.231.2.110/path/inventado",
 "http://dominio-3-468658.com/path2",
 "http://dominio-3-468658.com/path2/path1",
 "http://dominio-3-468658.com/path2/path2",
 "http://subdominio.dominio-3-468658.com/path2",
 "http://www.dominio-3-468658.com/path2",
 "http://este-se-repite.re/AP-448055"]

 require 'uri'

 uris.group_by{|u| URI(u).host}.values
 # => [
 #  ["http://dominio-1-736865.com/path1"], 
 #  ["http://dominio-2-570941.com/path2"], 
 #  ["http://102.160.194.146/path4"], 
 #  ["http://142.231.2.110", "http://142.231.2.110/path/inventado"], ["http://dominio-3-468658.com/path2", "http://dominio-3-468658.com/path2/path1", "http://dominio-3-468658.com/path2/path2"], 
 #  ["http://subdominio.dominio-3-468658.com/path2"], 
 #  ["http://www.dominio-3-468658.com/path2"], 
 #  ["http://este-se-repite.re/AP-448055"]
 #]
```

Finally, if you want to put domains with "www." in the same bucket with their naked versions:

```
uris.group_by{|u| URI(u).host.sub(/^www\./, '')}
=> {"dominio-1-736865.com"=>["http://dominio-1-736865.com/path1"],
 "dominio-2-570941.com"=>["http://dominio-2-570941.com/path2"],
 "102.160.194.146"=>["http://102.160.194.146/path4"],
 "142.231.2.110"=>["http://142.231.2.110", "http://142.231.2.110/path/inventado"],
 "dominio-3-468658.com"=>
  ["http://dominio-3-468658.com/path2", "http://dominio-3-468658.com/path2/path1", "http://dominio-3-468658.com/path2/path2", "http://www.dominio-3-468658.com/path2"],
 "subdominio.dominio-3-468658.com"=>["http://subdominio.dominio-3-468658.com/path2"],
 "este-se-repite.re"=>["http://este-se-repite.re/AP-448055"]}
```

Comment: Regex is not a problem, it's a solution ;-)

Comment: @mrzasa not according to [Jamie Zawinski](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247) :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Enumerable#group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Enumerable.html#group_by-method) :

```
a.group_by {|url| url.match(/http:\/\/([^\/]*)\/?/)[1] }.values
# ["http://dominio-2-570941.com/path2"],
# ["http://102.160.194.146/path4"],
# ["http://142.231.2.110", "http://142.231.2.110/path/inventado"],
# ["http://dominio-3-468658.com/path2",
#  "http://dominio-3-468658.com/path2/path1",
#  "http://dominio-3-468658.com/path2/path2"],
# ["http://subdominio.dominio-3-468658.com/path2"],
# ["http://www.dominio-3-468658.com/path2"],
# ["http://este-se-repite.re/AP-448055"]]
```

Regex explanation (without escaping)
`http://([^/]*)/?`

- `http://` matches prefix (same in every address)
- `([^/]*)` captures host part - everything but slash `/`
- `/?` optional slash ending the address

Comment: Yes, but I would like to clasify, into the corresponding box

Comment: Edited, changed to `group_by`